# Require field validation in telerik GridDropDownColumn

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

How to add Require field validation in Telerick RadGrid GridDropDownColumn?

```
<telerik:GridDropDownColumn DataField="DEPT_ID" DataSourceID="SqlDSDeptType"
EnableEmptyListItem="true" EmptyListItemText="None" EmptyListItemValue="0" HeaderText="Depatment Type" ListTextField="DEPT_NAME" ListValueField="DEPT_ID" UniqueName="DEPT_ID">
</telerik:GridDropDownColumn>`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing this for quite some time and has worked out really well for me.

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Depatment Type" UniqueName="DEPT_ID">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDeptName"
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <telerik:RadDropDownList runat="server" ID="comboDepts"
            DataSourceID="SqlDSDeptType"
            DataTextField="DEPT_NAME" DataValueField="DEPT_ID">
        </telerik:RadDropDownList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvcomboDepts" runat="server"
            Display="Dynamic" CssClass="validationClass"
            ValidationGroup="grvgName"
            ControlToValidate="comboDepts"
            ErrorMessage="Department cannot be empty"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <telerik:RadDropDownList runat="server" ID="comboDepts"
            DataSourceID="SqlDSDeptType"
            DataTextField="DEPT_NAME" DataValueField="DEPT_ID">
        </telerik:RadDropDownList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvcomboDepts" runat="server"
            Display="Dynamic" CssClass="validationClass"
            ValidationGroup="grvgName"
            ControlToValidate="comboDepts"
            ErrorMessage="Department cannot be empty"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

CSS

```
.validationClass {
    background-color: #FFCCCC;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: I'm going to add, you can use an asp.net DropDownList and a required field validator. If you do this, you have to add the initial value to the validator. This is working for me: 

<EditItemTemplate>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="DdlOrderedFrom" runat="server" Width="95px"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="Required" ControlToValidate="DdlOrderedFrom"  InitialValue="0" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" />   </EditItemTemplate>